# How do I redirect my webpage with Javascript or jQuery ?? Javascript redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have used the Webpage redirection with PHP. But I want to do it with Javascript or jQuery if it is possible.
I want to redirect the user to another page when he clicks on a button or something like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Why are you preferring one over the other? Give us some context so that we might be able to suggest some alternatives for you.

Comment: This question shows no research effort.

Comment: Amazingly, a Google search for "JavaScript redirect" yields a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods for javascript redirection. You can use any of these methods:

```
window.location.href = ”submit.php”;
```

or

```
window.location.replace("http://google.com");
```

or

```
window.location.assign("http://bing.com");
```

I would suggest **location.href** for that.

You can also have a look at this helpful [Javascript redirect tutorial](http://jstricks.com/javascript-redirect-page-redirection/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the attr() method of jQuery to redirect a web page:

```
var url = "http://google.com";
$(location).attr('href',url);
```